# Search Bar from the list I am using as a web part

Tags: search

I have created a SharePoint page and have inserted a web part. This web part is a list from another library on SharePoint. This has successfully worked however, on the actual list (not the web part version), there is a search bar, but the web part doesn't include the search bar when inserted into the new page. is there a way to also bring the search bar with the list. I have tried inserting a search bar through web part but it just gives me a search bar for all of the SharePoint library we have. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the web part and in the Miscellaneous Section select/check Display Search box. make sure you use default styleview.

**Otherwise** you can use HTML Form web part to search List/Library items.